# How to extract a string from parent string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string url as follows:

```
var url = '/test/mybin/processes/edit.jsp?id={processId}';
```

I want to extract the string `"processId"` from above url. I can get it using `indexOf` and substring methods, but is there a better alternative to do it? Can we do it using Regex?

Comment: for such a simple string deconstruction, use string operations. regex is massive overkill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. Most of the sugeestions below work. ,But I would like to know which is the best option from performance aspect? Using Regex or match or indexOf/substring?

Comment: Why the concern about performance? Is that an operation your application is going to repeat gazillions of times in a short period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a regex:

```
url.match(/\{([^}]*)\}/)[1];
```

But for this simple pattern, using `indexOf` and `substring`, while not as terse, will have much better performance. [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Answer (score 1):

```
var procid = url.split("id=")[1];
```

Comment: This will include the braces in the extracted string, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, it will.  I assumed the brackets were to exemplify a variable

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings has regex support embeded:

```
var processId = url.match(/\?id=(.+)/)[1];
```

Only thing U need - be familiar with regular expressions

And if braces are problem:

```
var processId = url.match(/\?id=\{(.+)\}/)[1];
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me {processId}. What I want is processId

Comment: This will include the braces in the extracted string, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Thought that braces was just as placeholders ) var processId = url.match(/\?id=\{(.+)\}/)[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
'/test/mybin/processes/edit.jsp?id={processId}'.split('{')[1].split('}')[0]
```

Comment: Ypu should actually try it yourself, just get the concept of using `split` and `join`